# FileAppender recreate file

Tags: java, log4j

I have done class `FileRollerAppender` that extends `FileAppender`. In my new class I need to rename current file and start new one from begining. Procedure that renames file.

```
public void rollOver() 
        {   
...        
        closeFile();
...
        File file = new File(fileName);
        file.renameTo(target);
    }
```

Now, when logger tryes log "hello" I have exception:

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to write [2014-02-18 09:21:42,941 26   [main] DEBUG sys.SuperBase  - hello
].
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:38)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:129)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:146)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:204)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:126)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.write(QuietWriter.java:39)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:292)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:150)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:221)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:187)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:372)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:241)
    at sys.SuperBase.debug(SuperBase.java:93)
    at log.FileRollerAppender.main(FileRollerAppender.java:157)
```

How to tell logger recreate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason to create this yourself? Log4j has already `RollingFileAppender` with several rolling strategies - reaching max size, on data/hour change and on startup. See more [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RolloverStrategies)

If you do want to implement your own, you can take a look at log4j's code to see how it is implemented

Comment: Got super.setFile(fileName, true, this.bufferedIO, this.bufferSize); from RollingFileAppender. It works